# PostgresSQL bit length differences

Tags: postgresql

Postgres search not returning as expected, two searches apparently the same doing different things.

In Postgres SQL, I'm failing to find a record with a search string but the reason is not apparent, in Pgadmin4 the first search works and the second does not, the first search was entered by first doing a wildcard search and copying the result into the search of the first one, the second one was just typed in.

```
-- returns the band
select * from artist where artist.name = 'blink-182'

-- returns nothing
select * from artist where artist.name = 'blink-182'

-- to get the result set
select * from artist where artist.name like 'blink%'
```

Narrowing down the issue I noted that the bit length of each search is different.

I'm completely new to PostgreSQL (but not SQL) so I'm sure there is something obvious I'm missing or haven't understood but I just can't see it.

[image: screenshot from Pgadmin4]

Comment: My first thought is to check the specific characters. Visually the characters seem the same but they might not be. There are for instance multiple unicode characters that visually represent a dash.

Comment: Probably what seems like the same symbols aren't really the same? E.g. maybe a dash is some variation (there are many dashes in unicode). A tool like this could help: https://freetools.textmagic.com/unicode-detector

Comment: Okay, I'll try a find and replace to regularise the dash and see if that works, thanks.

Comment: I just tried that utility, yes they are different, in pgadmin4 it represents them the same but in that utility one dash is visually longer than the other, thanks.

Comment: Could be an encoding issue. Please show your exact SQL: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some character that either looks like an ASCII character, but is different (like `–` or `ο`), or a character that is invisible. To see what's going on, look at the UTF-8 value of the string:

```
SELECT convert_to(name, 'UTF8') FROM artist WHERE name LIKE 'blink%';
```